# Database table size did not decrease proportionately

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4, vacuum

I am working with a PostgreSQL 8.4.13 database.
Recently I had around around 86.5 million records in a table. I deleted almost all of them - only 5000 records are left. I ran

```
reindex
```

and

```
vacuum analyze
```

after deleting the rows. But I still see that the table is occupying a large disk space:

```
jbossql=> SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('my_table'));
pg_size_pretty 
----------------
7673 MB
```

Also, the index value of the remaining rows are pretty high still - like in the million range. I thought after vacuuming and re-indexing, the index of the remaining rows would start from 1.

I read the documentation and it's pretty clear that my understanding of re-indexing was skewed.

But nonetheless, my intention is to reduce the table size after delete operation and bring down the index values so that the read operations (`SELECT`) from the table does not take that long - currently it's taking me around 40 seconds to retrieve just one record from my table.

#### Update

Thanks Erwin. I have corrected the pg version number.

```
vacuum full
```

worked for me. I have one follow up question here:
[Restart primary key numbers of existing rows after deleting most of a big table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526813/reatart-primary-key-numbers-of-existing-rows-after-deleting-most-of-a-big-table)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thx. I have created a new question for my follow up question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526813/re-index-the-primary-key-column-after-full-vacuuming Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To actually return disk space to the OS, run [**`VACUUM FULL`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html).

Further reading:

- [VACUUM returning disk space to operating system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37032/3684)